# How to show a view programmably in a position defined in plugin.xml?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to show views (multiple) in my plugin source code using:

```
showView(id, id2, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE)
```

This view is first closed, shown after my proccess completed.

I defined the view and its positon in plugin.xml as below:

```
        name="..."
        icon="..."
        category="..."
        class="..."
        allowMultiple="true"            
        id="myid"
```

extension

```
point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions"
  perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective"
```

view

```
       ratio="0.5"
       relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline"
       relationship="stack"
       visible="false"
       id="myid"
```

I want to show them top right area of perspective (the same as Outline view).

If I set visible true or open my view manually in GUI, it appears top right as I expected,
but when I use "`showView()`" above,  views always appears at the bottom (console, problems, etc.)

How can I show my views always top right programmably?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add placeholders for the rest of your views, that have a secondary ID.  Another entry in your perspectiveExtension with a compound ID and a wildcard should work: `myid:*`.  See [IPageLayout](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPageLayout.html) javadoc for more information.