# Adding view at the top Editor through dynamically

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse RCP Application

we adding a view in programmatically using Below code

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("browser.scview",Integer.toString(++instanceNum), IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);
```

but this code by default add view at the bottom. but i need to  add view in the top how can achieve this through code please help me

Comment: Please see this question, hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500678/how-to-show-a-view-programmably-in-a-position-defined-in-plugin-xml

Answer (score 1):

Default view placement is defined in the IPerspectiveFactory, if are using a perspective that you have created you can add what is called a place holder for the view ID you want to show on the specific IFolderLayout defined in the pespective like this:

```
// Top left: Project Explorer view and Bookmarks view placeholder
IFolderLayout topLeft = layout.createFolder("topLeft", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f,
editorArea);
topLeft.addView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);
topLeft.addPlaceholder(IPageLayout.ID_BOOKMARKS);
```

Then with a place holder for the same ID of the view you want to show in code it will be displayed in that folder. If you are confused, lookup the API's for IPageLayout and IFolderLayout. If this is a perspective that you did not define yourself